# Simple JOIN slow, very fast with STRAIGHT_JOIN but not for all cases

Tags: sql, join, indexing, mariadb

To place a video in one or more categories I have the following tables:

- `Video (id, url, title, viewCount)`  ~1,000,000 rows
- `VideoCategory (id, videoId, categoryId` ~6,000,000 rows
- `Category (id, name)` ~200 rows

Index on `VideoCategory(categoryId, videoId)`
Unique Index on `Category(name)`

The following query, to get 10 most viewed videos in the 'Cars' category is too slow (~5.5 sec). The 'Cars' category contains 200,000 videos.

```sql
SELECT v.* FROM Video v
  JOIN VideoCategory vc ON vc.videoId = v.id
  JOIN Category c ON vc.categoryId = c.id
  WHERE c.name = 'Cars' 
  ORDER BY v.viewCount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

When querying a category that only contains 100 videos it takes ~0.05 sec.

`EXPLAIN` of query for 'Cars' category.

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                      | key                | key_len | ref                   | rows   | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c     | const  | name_UNIQUE                        | name_UNIQUE        | 322     | const                 | 1      | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | vc    | ref    | fk_Category_idx,category_video_idx | category_video_idx | 8       | const                 | 493988 | Using index                                  |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | v     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY            | 8       | VideoDB.vc.videoId    | 1      | Using where                                  |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

How can I speed it up (hopefully 0.1 sec. or less)? Leaving out the `ORDER BY` has a massive impact but it obviously doesn't give me the result I want.

**Update**
I played around with `STRAIGHT_JOIN` and observed some interesting things with the following query:

```sql
SELECT v.* FROM Video v
STRAIGHT_JOIN VideoCategory vc ON v.id = vc.videoId
WHERE vc.categoryId = (SELECT id FROM Category WHERE name = 'Cars')
ORDER BY v.viewCount ASC
LIMIT 10
```

It returns in 0.011 sec! I also removed the `JOIN Category c` and replaced it with `WHERE vc.categoryId = (SELECT id FROM Category WHERE name = 'Cars')` which returns immediately with 0 results if the `Category.name` doesn't exist.

Unfortunately just throwing in a `STRAIGHT_JOIN` doesn't fix everything, it is only fast(er) for categories with ~1000+ videos, the more videos the faster it seems. For a category containing less than 100 videos it gets extremely slow, taking out the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` makes it very fast again.

For a query this simple I expected the planner to find the optimal path. What's going on here?

Another observation is that changing the order from `ASC` to `DESC` will make the query slower again for some categories but not for other? (e.g. ASC will take 0.01 sec. and DESC will take 0.8 sec.)

Comment: I'm not a MariaDB person (more MSSQL) but here's my thoughts. The strategy used to do this view is to a) get all the video IDs from Video_Category, b) get all the corresponding videos c) sort them by views, then d) take the highest 10. If there are only 100 videos, it only needs to sort 100 records. However, with 200k records, it needs to look up and sort all of them. You could try an index in videos by ViewCount which could do the opposite - simply read the 'most viewed' videos, then check if they're of the relevant category. This would be fast for common categories but may make others slower

Comment: Thanks for the input @seanb. I can understand that's the path it's taking so I tried adding an index on ```viewCount``` to help with the sorting but it's not improving. I can't shake the feeling that I'm leaving performance on the table, it's just simple JOINs and sorting by (indexed) BIGINTs columns.

Comment: Does mariadb have Top N Sort? It's a feature in SSMS that is (essentially) linear time with large input and small output. If no then I'll have to agree with @seanb - you're probably stuck in the ballpark of 5 seconds.

Comment: If you can change data structures & processing, you can add the column `viewCount` to the VideoCategory table and maintain it there (e.g., when you update Video, you also update VideoCategory). Have an index on categoryID, viewCount & videoID (in that order), and another on videoID (for identifying videoIDs for updating). If real-time isn't critical, you could also make another table, maintained in batch process, and SELECT from this table. Columns categoryID, videoID, viewCount. PK is videoID & categoryID (in order), and clustered index categoryID, viewCount, videoID (in order).

Answer (score 0):

That order by is going to cost a lot for 200k records. One idea is to create a top 10 table that gets updated periodically, so you can just show entries from the new top 10 table which would be way quicker for the user and easier on the db load.

Comment: I know 200k sounds like a lot but I hoped an index on ```viewCount``` or ```viewCount, id``` could help here. After all it's a sort on BIGINTs, a 64-bit value, surely that shouldn't be taking 5 seconds?

Comment: An index on viewCount doesn't help, unfortunately. Following the same (likely) execution plan outlined by seanb:


1. Get the video category ID

2. Get the video IDs from VideoCategory using an index seek (this is fast). However, these aren't ordered by viewCount.


Herein lies the problem. On one side you have the video table sorted by viewCount, but on the other side you have a list of video IDs that aren't sorted by any metric. After doing the key lookup you still have to sort the result regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal resolution of your origin query is to lookup the `Category.id` for "cars" which is done.

The query plan then falls over due to the lack of indexing on `VideoCategory`.

As I assume lookups are from `categoryId` ->  `videoId` there should be a `categoryId` index. But ideally as a joining table `(categoryId, videoId)` is probably the most suitable composite primary key that would improve your query. If there reverse resolution from `videoId` -> `categoryId` is required, a secondary key `videoId`. The primary key is already included at the end of secondary keys.

The last problem of `viewCount` is a hard one. Some query optimization like [rowid_filter](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rowid-filtering-optimization/) might help.